# Illustrator custom brush: Corners get automatically round

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush

I generated a custom art brush that strangely shows rounded corners instead of "real" corners.
[image]

How is that possible?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of a larger area that shows your custom brush settings and your stroke panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Art brushed are "stretched" between guides along the path.

Art Brushes don't have sharp corners. The art essentially has "smooth joints" where it is bent around the path. As opposed to "mitered joints" which have an angle.

Based upon this, and your previous question, I really  think you need to edit the arrowheads and [create a custom arrowhead](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/illustrator-creating-arrowheads.html) for use with a standard path. That way you get circle end caps in addition to sharp corners where you want them.